# query to get contact from particular associated email from a database table

Tags: android

I have made a registration form in android and storing its data in sqlite database.
I have 4 fields in registration form i.e. Contact No, Name, Email, Password
Now i just want to get a contact no associated with particular email from the database.
which query is perfect for doing that.
I have tried this but not worked.

```
public String getContact(String a) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER + " where " + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = '" +a + "'" , null);
    String str = null;
    if (c.moveToNext()) {
        do {
            str = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("password"));
        }
        while (c.moveToFirst());
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String getUserContactNumber(String email) {
    String userContact=“”;

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + COLUMN_USER_CONTACT+ " FROM " + TABLE_USER+ " WHERE " + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL+ "=?", new String[]{email});

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        userContact =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_USER_CONTACT));
    }

    cursor.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    databaseHelper.close();

    return userContact;
}
```